# Converting a list into a string

Tags: python, string, list, function, join

I'm taking user inputted strings continuously and then trying to remove any character that is not a character or digit.

The method that I developed involves splitting a string by the white space and then analyzing each word to find invalid characters.

I'm having a hard time putting the words back together with spaces in between each word. I've tried using ' '.join(list) but it puts a space in between each character or digit.

Comment: Instead of `' '.join(string)` you could have simply done `''.join(string)`. (But your specific problem can be solved more easily)

Comment: this code as is not working. The first while has nothing indented after it

Comment: I copied and pasted my code here but I had to indent using 4 spaces. Some of my tabs didn't show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, @Ashwini's answer is better than this, But if you still want to do it just with loops

```
strings = raw_input("type something")
while(True):
    MyString = ""
    if strings == "stop": break
    for string in strings.split():
        for char in string:
            if(char.isalnum()): MyString += char
        MyString += " "
    print MyString
    strings = raw_input("continue : ")
```

**Sample Run**

```
$ python Test.py
type somethingWelcome to$%^ Python
Welcome to Python 
continue : I love numbers 1234 but not !@#$
I love numbers 1234 but not  
continue : stop
```

**EDIT**

**Python 3 Version:**

As indicated by Ashwini in the comments, storing the characters in a list and printing the list with join at the end.

```
strings = input("type something : ")
while(True):
    MyString = []
    if strings == "stop": break
    for string in strings.split():
        for char in string:
            if(char.isalnum()): MyString.append(char)
        MyString.append(" ")
    print (''.join(MyString))
    strings = input("continue : ")
```

**Sample Run:**

```
$ python3 Test.py
type something : abcd
abcd 
continue : I love Python 123
I love Python 123 
continue : I hate !@#
I hate  
continue : stop
```

Comment: I ran your code and got a different output. Is it because I'm using python 3?

Comment: Note that string concatenations done using `+` or `+=` are quite [in-efficient](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation), append the characters to a list and use a join at the end.

Comment: @HarryHarry replace `raw_input` with `input` and use `print` as a function in py3.x

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks yaar :) Incorporated your comments as well, in the Python3 version.

Comment: @HarryHarry Updated the solution with python3 version. Please check

Answer (score 2):

## Simple loop based solution:

```
strs = "foo12 #$dsfs 8d"
ans = []
for c in strs:
    if c.isalnum():
        ans.append(c)
    elif c.isspace():  #handles all types of white-space characters \n \t etc.
        ans.append(c)
print ("".join(ans))
#foo12 dsfs 8d
```

## One-liners:

Use `str.translate`:

```
>>> from string import punctuation, whitespace
>>> "foo12 #$dsfs 8d".translate(None,punctuation)
'foo12 dsfs 8d'
```

To remove white-space as well:

```
>>> "foo12 #$dsfs 8d".translate(None,punctuation+whitespace)
'foo12dsfs8d'
```

or `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = "foo12 #$dsfs 8d"
>>> re.sub(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z]','',strs)
'foo12dsfs8d'
```

Using `str.join`, `str.isalnum` and `str.isspace`:

```
>>> strs = "foo12 #$dsfs 8d"
>>> "".join([c for c in strs if c.isalnum() or c.isspace()])
'foo12 dsfs 8d'
```

Comment: I don't think I can use translate. Is it possible to do it another way?

Comment: @HarryHarry What's the issue with `str.translate`?

Comment: It's a rule that my professor has. If we haven't covered it in class then it can't be used.

Comment: @HarryHarry see my update solution, can you use `str` methods?

Comment: @HarryHarry Just to note: it would be nice if you included such information about what you're allowed to use and any restrictions so as to not waste people's time that are trying to help you. In fact - I would suggest [editing your question now](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17506518/edit) to include such information ;)

Comment: Yeah. Is translate a str method?

Comment: @HarryHarry yes, you can also use `str.isalnum()` and  `str.isspace()`.

Comment: how bout  `filter(lambda x:x.isalnum() or x.isspace(),"asdasd..as.d")`

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. See comments for more info:

```
def sanitize(word):
    """use this to clean words"""
    return ''.join([x for x in word if x.isalpha()] )

n = input("type something")

#simpler way of detecting stop
while(n[-4:] != 'stop'):
    n += "  " + input("continue : ")

n = n.split()[:-1]
# if yuo use list= you are redefining the standard list object
my_list = [sanitize(word) for word in n]

print(my_list)
strn = ' '.join(my_list)
print(strn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with joins and a list comprehension.

```
def goodChars(s):
  return " ".join(["".join([y for y in x if y.isdigit() or y.isalpha()]) for x in s.split()])
```